# Save Saiku query to reuse later

Tags: pentaho, saiku

I'm using Pentaho with Saiku. It's usual to be exploring data and find some interesting info. I need then to save the query (columns, dimensions and filters) that resulted on that info.

But I can't find a way to do that. I'm able to click on the save button and save a *.saiku file. But when I open those files, Saiku shows an empty query, I need to select a cube and build the whole query again.

Is there an easy way to save a Saiku query and open it back, so that columns, rows and filters are already selected and the report (table or chart) is queried and presented automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems saving Saiku queries recently, in the latest pentaho version. I think you can try the solution presented in http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-13666 that consists in moving some jar files:

Source folder: ../system/sparkl/lib

Destination folder: ../system/saiku/lib

files:

cpf-core-7.1.0.0-12.jar,

cpf-pentaho-7.1.0.0-12.jar,

cpk-core-7.1.0.0-12.jar

cpk-pentaho5-7.1.0.0-12.jar

--

Also, if you want some simpler and faster way, just for emergencies, I'd suggest you can switch your Saiku query to MDX mode and copy the resulting MDX query, so you can use it later.